# Inertia.js SSR with Laravel-Vue3 project throwing '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' error in Webpack

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I'm trying to make a working ssr project with laravel-vue3. I am using webpack as compiler. I am using inertia.js for SSR. but although my project is running, only the #app div is visible when viewed from the page source. **php artisan inertia:start-ssr** when I run the command in console it says "Cannot access '**WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT**' before initialization" i get the error.

app.js

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp, Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import store from './src/store/store'
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { fab } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import { far } from "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons";
library.add(fas);
library.add(fab);
library.add(far);
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress'
import route from "ziggy-js";
import AppAxios from "./src/utils/appAxios";
import Maska from 'maska'
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css";
import "@vueform/slider/themes/default.css"
import Api from "./src/utils/Api/index"
import helpers from "./helpers";
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css'
import $ from "jquery";
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

const clickOutside = {
    beforeMount: (el, binding) => {
        el.clickOutsideEvent = event => {
            if (!(el === event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
                binding.value();
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener("click", el.clickOutsideEvent);
    },
    unmounted: el => {
        document.removeEventListener("click", el.clickOutsideEvent);
    },
};

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        const RootApp = createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) });
        RootApp.use(plugin);
        RootApp.use(store);
        RootApp.use(Maska);
        RootApp.config.globalProperties.helpers = helpers
        RootApp.mixin({ methods: { route } });
        RootApp.component("FontAwesomeIcon", FontAwesomeIcon);
        RootApp.component('Link', Link);
        RootApp.config.globalProperties.$appAxios = AppAxios;
        RootApp.config.globalProperties.$route = route;
        RootApp.config.globalProperties.$api = Api;
        RootApp.directive("click-outside", clickOutside)
        RootApp.mount(el);
    },
})


InertiaProgress.init({
    delay: 250,

    color: '#fff',

    includeCSS: true,

    showSpinner: true
})
```

ssr.js

```
import { createSSRApp, h } from 'vue'
import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-renderer'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import createServer from '@inertiajs/server'

createServer((page) => createInertiaApp({
    page,
    render: renderToString,
    resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
    setup({ app, props, plugin }) {
        return createSSRApp({
            render: () => h(app, props),
        }).use(plugin)
    },
}))
```

webpack.ssr.mix.js

```
const path = require('path')
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

mix
    .options({ manifest: false })
    .js('resources/js/ssr.js', 'public/js')
    .vue({ version: 3, options: { optimizeSSR: true } })
    .alias({ '@': path.resolve('resources/js') })
    .webpackConfig({
        target: 'node',
        externals: [webpackNodeExternals()],
    })
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue();
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),
        },
    },
});
mix.copyDirectory('resources/static', 'public/static');

mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
    return {
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /(\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp|avif)$|^((?!font).)*\.svg$)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
                    options: {
                        esModule: false
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }
    };
});
```

I tried everything found in the inertia.js documentation. I tried what I saw in the forums but the error did not change. sometimes I got the error "document is not defined" but I couldn't solve it either